# How to make disappear some weird numbers in a pie chart with pgf-pie

Tags: pgf-pie

I am trying to make a simple pie chart with pgf-pie, but for a reason unknown to me the labels I use don't display correctly.

Here is the chunk of code I've copied from the manual into my .tex file :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[color ={ cyan!10 , cyan!40, cyan!70,  cyan!100}, explode=0.1] {10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is a screenshot of what I get :

[image: Numbers appear close to the labels]

And here is a picture of what I'd like to obtain :
[image: Screenshot taken from the manual]

Does anybody knows why I get these numbers and how to get rid of them ?

edit : Here is a minimal working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[color ={ cyan!10 , cyan!40, cyan!70,  cyan!100}, explode=0.1]{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. I get the error message: `! File ended while scanning use of \\pie.` Please edit the question and add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Right sorry I'll add a more complete version. Thanks to that I noticed that the problem only appears when I use [frenchb]{babel} so, thanks for the help !

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with your example. Nevertheless, the package name is `pgf-pie`. So you will get a warning, if you load it using `\usepackage{pgf-pie-0.2.1/pgf-pie}`. And if you load `pgfplots` (which is not needed for `pgf-pie`) you should set option `compat` (see the `pgfplots` manual for more information).

Comment: you find error in code snippet yourself. Correcting it (in your edit) in question means, that you not need an answer anymore ... Howrver, line `\usepackage{pgf-pie-0.2.1/pgf-pie}` is rather strange.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I modified my code according to your comment. However, I actually can reproduce the problem with the snippet I put in my post so... No clue about why it doesn't do it for you. I found a solution anyway (answer below)

@Zarko yep I changed that line to `\usepackage{pgf-pie}` ; the question was still opened because I still got the same unwanted behavior when compiling the code in my post with pdflatex.

Comment: Compare the file versions. See the list at the end of my answer. Maybe you need an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a missing `]` in the original question at the end of the option list of `\pie` in your code snippet. Nevertheless, with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[color ={ cyan!10 , cyan!40, cyan!70,  cyan!100}, explode=0.1] {10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

If you want different colors, you should change option `color`, e.g.,

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie[color ={ cyan!10 , cyan!40, yellow, orange}, explode=0.1] {10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm using (excerpt from `log` file with `\listfiles`):

```
   babel.sty    2017/06/29 3.12 The Babel package
 frenchb.ldf    2017/04/30 v3.3a French support from the babel system
 pgf-pie.sty    2011/10/02 v0.2 Some LaTeX macros for pie chart by using PGF/Tikz package.
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
```

Nevertheless, depending on the labels and the `babel` languages, it could be necessary to use

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

after loading `pgf-pie`. But this is speculative only, because I did not find an example for the need with `pfg-pie`.

Comment: Thanks but this typo was only in the post, not in my actual code (it appears I'm not very gifted at copying and pasting... somehow).
While trying to do a functioning example, I discovered that the problem appears only when I use
    `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}`
so this is probably just an incompatibility issue

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Weird numbers before label when using pgf-pie.

[image]

I also use the

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

on my document.

I tried the solution from @Schweinebacke.
I just added \usetikzlibrary{babel} after \usepackage{pgf-pie}, like this :

```
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

And that’s it ! No more issue with labels.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show in an answer an compilable TeX code for a fast proof!