# Attributes are being printed as text inside pgf-pie, causing "There is no ... in font nullfont!" errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, miktex, pgf-pie

`pgf-pie` keeps giving me headaches.

This is my LaTeX code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[color={black!10, black!20, black!30}]
    {62/\TeX\ Live and Mac\TeX,
     32/MiK\TeX\ and Pro\TeX t, 6/Other \TeX}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I use MiKTeX and PdfLaTeX as my PDF engine, when I run it the [log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/px4tzvwsbgjqorx/pie-test.log?dl=0) returns these errors:

```
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no k in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ! in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no k in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ! in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 2 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no k in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ! in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 3 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
```

And the PDF looks like this:

[image: Pie chart with properties printed as text]

To me it looks like attributes/options are being accidentally being printed as text.

I've found similar issues (e.g. [tikzpicture options causing "There is no [ in font nullfont!"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121154/tikzpicture-options-causing-there-is-no-in-font-nullfont)), but none of these pointed me in the direction of solving this.

UPDATE: This question appeared to be a duplicate. One of the answers put me on the track to the the answer on this issue: [Problem generating pie chart with pgf-pie package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469477/problem-generating-pie-chart-with-pgf-pie-package)

That solved it for me.

Comment: I cannot reproduce these problems when I compile your code on my just updated TeXLive2019 installation with `PDFLaTeX`. So please provide more information on the installation you are using.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'm using MikTex (with PDFLaTex)

Comment: Your code works perfectly (note that I'm also using `PDFLaTeX` in `MikTeX`). Problem lies may be in your `MikTeX` installation...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Did a reinstall of MikTex. Problem persists

Comment: @gijswijs Can you post your `.log` file?

Comment: @MadyYuvi, Sure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/px4tzvwsbgjqorx/pie-test.log?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

For some reason pgf-pie outputs the color in one place. You can patch the command.

But I wouldn't recommend the package. It quite ruthlessly redefines user commands like `\color` and so it bound to break other code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\pgfpie@findColor{\thecolor \breakforeach }{\breakforeach}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[color={red!10, black!20, black!30}]
    {62/\TeX\ Live Mac\TeX,
     32/MiK\TeX\ and Pro\TeX t, 6/Other \TeX}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That doesn't yield the desired result. But I'm open for suggestions of alternative packages that can make pie charts.

Comment: what do mean by it doesn't give the desired result? It looks okay for me (the red!10 is only there because I wanted to be sure, that the user colors are used, you can change it back to black!10).

Comment: I meant that your problem didn't solve the printing of the attributes for me. But it *did* put me on the right track to finding the solution.
See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469477/problem-generating-pie-chart-with-pgf-pie-package

Comment: I don't get the overprinting, only the missing char messages in a current tex system.