# labels with debug information

Tags: labels, debugging, pgf-pie

On macOS, I tried the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie{47/Rice,32/Wheat,22/Other}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I observe is not what I expect with labels:[image]

It is like there is some debug info attached to the label (I would guess label position/angle).
Any way to disable this behaviour ?

- **2020-09-21 edit**: remove unrelated code (`[text=legend]`)
- **2020-09-21 edit**: suggestion from @TorbjørnT. solved my issue. My question is a duplicate of [How to make disappear some weird numbers in a pie chart with pgf-pie](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378649/how-to-make-disappear-some-weird-numbers-in-a-pie-chart-with-pgf-pie/378652#378652)

Comment: Hi, welcome. As far as I remember there is no debugging features in that packages, so probably just a bug :) That said, I do not get that result when I try, so you may have a different version than me. Have you downloaded the package manually, or are you using the one that is in MacTeX?

Comment: Actually, it might be a conflict with `babel`, are you using that package in your document? If you do, try adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{pgf-pie}`. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378652/)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Brilliant! your suggestion solved my issue. I missed the question your referred to. Thank you!